# Pages not in directory showing up on google analytic

Tags: google-analytics

I've been using google analytics for my website for awhile now and haven't had any problems. Just today though I checked the all pages tab under Behavior->Site Content and found something very strange. A bunch of pages that aren't on in my websites directory are now appearing there and saying they have traffic (albeit very little). Here's a link to an image of the pages: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i138Z.jpg

I've verified that non of these pages exist on my live server or in the directory on my local machine. Does anyone know what might be causing this? Or how I can get rid of these pages on my website? I've searched around on google but have had no luck figuring out whats going on.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Is it possible someone else is using your unique code for google analytics? From what I remember they just assign your data via the unique identifier. Also, did you actually attempt to go to the suspicious pages, or simply check the directory?

Comment: I've gone to the pages and am getting this page "Gateway GEO-IP Alert

This request is blocked by the SonicWALL Gateway Geo IP Service.
Country Name:Latvia. 
Responder IP:193.105.240.44" I think you might be right with someone else using our unique code.

Answer (score 1):

Timothy it looks like you are just seeing Referral/Referrer Spam.

Here are a couple of my favorite links on the subject:

- [Definitive Guide to Removing Referral Spam](http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/)
- [What is Referrer Spam and How to stop it](http://www.ohow.co/what-is-referrer-spam-how-stop-it-guide/)
- [4 things you must know about Spam in Google Analytics](http://www.ohow.co/things-you-must-know-about-spam-in-google-analytics/)

Comment: This seems to be the problem! Thanks for the links, this should give me a great starting point to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good idea to have a Raw View with no filters, but then also a filtered view with a include:yourdomainname.com added, to filter out any possible hits sent by people copying your GA tracking code.